# Setting a column value to the previous records value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I want to select a record, and the record that becomes before and after it based on an id. For all NULL records for FirstName, I want to set the FirstName to be that of the previous record.
I have code that successfully gets a table of values before and after, but how can I update the value? I've tried the code below but I get an error like this

```
The multi-part indentifier "CTE.FirstName" could not be bound
```

Anyone know what the issue is? Please note, I'm using SQL Server 2008 so i can't use LAG or LEAD

```
 WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.BusinessEntityID),
    p.FirstName
    FROM Person.Person p
    )
    SELECT
    prev.FirstName PreviousValue,
    CTE.FirstName,
    nex.FirstName NextValue
    FROM CTE
    LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
    LEFT JOIN CTE nex ON nex.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1
    IF(CTE.FirstName IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Person SET FirstName = prev.FirstName 
        END
```

Comment: Are you working with SQL Server 1012 or higher? If yes, check the new LEAD and LAG functions.

Comment: @Scoregraphic 2008 is indicated in the question.

Comment: I'm using sql server 2008 so i can't make use of LEAD or LAG

Comment: Yes, the issue is that you are trying to use `IF` as if it were a row by row operator, which is not. After your `SELECT`, the `CTE` no longer exists either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update a `cte`, so something like this should do it:

```
WITH CTE AS (
             SELECT
                   rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.BusinessEntityID),
                   p.FirstName
             FROM Person.Person p
             )
UPDATE a
SET a.Firstname = prev.Firstname
FROM CTE a
JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = a.rownum - 1
WHERE a.FirstName IS NULL
```

Comment: This is fantastic - cheers! also, how would I update a second value? Can I add a second update post the first?

Comment: You can `SET` any number of fields:  `SET a.FirstName = prev.Firstname, a.othercol = prev.othercol`  etc.

Comment: Actually, my two updates are using separate WHERE clauses - Is this possible to include two updates with different WHERE's?

Comment: It depends on the criteria, but you could likely use `CASE`, ie:  `SET a.Firstname = CASE WHEN a.FirstName IS NULL THEN prev.FirstName ELSE a.FirstName END, a.othercol = CASE WHEN a.othercol IS NULL THEN prev.othercol ELSE a.othercol END`

And you could still use `WHERE` criteria to save some time by not bothering with rows that need no updates: `WHERE a.FirstName IS NULL OR a.othercol` IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Your update is a separate statement from the `select`.  If you want to do this in an update, try:

```
WITH CTE AS (
     SELECT rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.BusinessEntityID),
            p.FirstName
     FROM Person.Person p
)
UPDATE p
    SET FirstName = prev.FirstName 
    FROM CTE p JOIN
         CTE prev
         ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
    WHERE CTE.FirstName IS NULL;
```

The `left join` isn't important here, because you are only changing rows where `FirstName IS NULL`.  The `left join` would set the `NULL` value to itself.